# SQL Server Database Optimization Strategy

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I am starting a new project using SQL Server for a medical office. Their current database (SQL Server 2008) have over 500,000 rows that span across 15+ tables. Currently they are complaining that their data entry application is very slow to generate reports and insert new data.

For my new system I was thinking of developing a two tiered database approach where the primary used SQL Server 2012 will only contain 3 months worth of rows and the second SQL Server 2012 would maintain all the data for the system. This way when users insert new data it will be entered into a much smaller system and when they query recent data the query should execute much faster. This system will also have reporting, but I think the reports will have to be generated from the larger data set.

My questions are as follows

1. Will a solution like this improve the overall performance of the database
2. Are there any scalability concerns with this solution?
3. What is the best way to transfer that data between the two servers each night?

If my solution makes no sense please feel free to offer any other solutions.

Comment: Inserting records would make the DB OLTP and generating reports will make the DB OLAP. The indexing strategies is very different for the two requirements.

Comment: 500.000 ROWS? 15 tables? Ok, anything less than a million rows is tiny - and 15 tables is a joke. Try 1 billion rows, adding 40 million per day, 200 tables. Do you know what an index is? That could b one thing slowing it down - not having indices.

Comment: If the problem is that the reports generate slowly, then you should focus on figuring out why that is.  Using Sql Server Profiler along with the Database Engine Tunine Adviser is a great way to do this.  Sometimes a small index can make a huge difference.  See my post regarding "A Beginner's Guide to Database Optimization" http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/sql-server-database-optimization-a-beginners-guide/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do this. Splitting your app into multiple databases will be a management nightmare. Plus, 500k records isn't that many, assuming that the records are of reasonable size.

Instead, go after the low-hanging fruit. Turn on logging and look at the access patterns. Which queries are slow? Figure out why. Do they lack indexes? Can the queries be simplified? Debug the problem.

Keep in mind that sometimes throwing hardware at the problem is the right solution. If you can solve the problem with an $800 server, do it. That's a lot cheaper than your time.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems after further investigation the report generation seems to be slow the sql queries (after looking into the profiler) are moving fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To chime in: 500K records is not so big.  You ought to be able to make the db work very speedily as is with some tuning.